# Probability of getting no worms in your box

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to work out the below fabricated scenario:

> Boxes of apples are checked for worms one at a time, and the probability that a given box of apples has worms is $p = 0.1$, independently of the others. If $6$ boxes of apples are tested, what is the probability that there are no boxes of apples infested with worms?

Now I know that we have two outcomes for each event, $\Omega =$ {$S,F$}.
So with six tests we have $2^6$ sets of outcomes. Now I want to find the number of sets of outcomes that have atleast one fail, which is $2^6-1$ since there is only one set with {$S,S,S,S,S,S$}

Probability of getting no worm boxes is, $1 - pr(\text{getting worms}) \longrightarrow$ $ 1 - \frac{63}{64}$ if they have an even chance of being success or fail(not sure if this is correct), so to factor in the $.1$ of being infested I am unsure what to do. I thought originally you would times the $63/64$ by .1, but that seems to increase the probability of getting all 6 non-defective over even one trial.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Or am I over complicating this and it is just $9^6$?

Comment: this is indeed ;)

Comment: @mookid I need a break xD

Comment: The outcomes don’t have an even chance of success or fail. Success is no worms, which happens 90% of the time. Your approach, listing all sequences of outcomes and finding the fraction you want, only works if the outcomes in your list are all equally likely. If they aren’t, you have to multiply each by its relative probability. Here, there’s only one no-worms sequence, so there’s no need to enumerate all the sequences, both wormy and not, but you do need to compute the no-worms sequence’s probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance of getting no worms in one box is $0.9$. The chance of getting no worms in two boxes is $0.9 \times 0.9$, since 90% of the time you will be lucky on the first box and 90% of *that* time you will be lucky on the second box. You can probably figure out where this is going.

Comment: What about probability a specific number, $n$, were infested? Would it be $1 - .9^{6-n}$?

Comment: The probability that exactly $n$ out of the $6$ boxes are infested is a more complicated problem, and you would have to use the formula for a binomial distribution.

Comment: Fixed my above comment. So it is more complex than that fixed one above? Okay I will look into it

Comment: One quick check for whether your formula for exactly $n$ infested boxes is correct is that if you sum the probabilities for $n=0$ through $n=6$, you should get $1$, since that covers all the cases.

Comment: @DisplayName : The probability of getting worms in $n$ boxes is $(1-0.9^n)$ and the probability of getting no worms in $(6-n)$ boxes is $(0.9^{6-n})$, and there are ${6 \choose n}$ arrangements of this. So the probability of getting exactly n infections is $\dfrac{(1-0.9^n)(0.9^{6-n})6!}{n!(6-n)!}$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That was a massive help, thank you Graham.